# In Boost serialization, boost::local_time::local_date_time gives error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost

I'm trying to serialize MyData but boost::local_time::local_date_time gives error :
**"Error    1   error C2512: 'boost::local_time::local_date_time_base<>' : no appropriate default constructor available"**

Below is the code :

// MyData.hpp file

```
struct MyData
{
std::string id;
std::string name;
boost::local_time::local_date_time time; 

private:
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template
void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
{
ar & id;
ar & name;
ar & time;  // when i comment this line, error goes off
} 

public:
MyData(void);
MyData(const parameter_strings & parms);

virtual ~MyData(void);
};
}

// MyData.cpp file

MyData::MyData(void)
{
}

MyData::~MyData(void)
{
}

MyData::MyData(const parameter_strings & parms)
{
// implementation aprt
}
```

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(MyData); BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(MyData,boost::serialization::object_serializable);
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(MyData,boost::serialization::track_selectively);

Please help on this topic, investing more time but till now no use.

Can i use posix date time to get current date and time ?? or where do i need to call the construtor for date-time.. ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs state](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/serialization.html):

> The boost::date_time library is compatible with the boost::serialization library's text and xml archives. The list of classes that are serializable are:
>
> - `boost::gregoriandate`
>     `date_duration`, `date_period`, `partial_date`, `nth_day_of_week_in_month`,
>     `first_day_of_week_in_month` `last_day_of_week_in_month`,
>     `first_day_of_week_before`, `first_day_of_week_after` `greg_month`,
>     `greg_day`, `greg_weekday`
> - `boost::posix_time`
>   `ptime`, `time_duration`, `time_period`

So, yes. But you should use `ptime` instead of local_date_time.

Now, first things first, the compiler is complaining that it doesn't know how to initialize the `time` member (since it has no default constructor). This has nothing to do with serialization:

```
struct Oops
{
    boost::local_time::local_date_time time; 
    Oops() { }
};
```

has the same problem already. Fix it:

```
struct FixedOops
{
    boost::local_time::local_date_time time; 
    FixedOops() : time(boost::local_time::not_a_date_time) 
    { 
    }
};
```

Now, to serializing:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/time_serialize.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>

struct parameter_strings {};

struct MyData
{
    std::string id;
    std::string name;
    boost::posix_time::ptime time; 

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & id;
            ar & name;
            ar & time;  // when i comment this line, error goes off
        } 

  public:
    MyData() : time(boost::posix_time::not_a_date_time) { }
    MyData(parameter_strings const&) : time(boost::posix_time::not_a_date_time) { }
    virtual ~MyData() { };
};

int main()
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
    MyData data;

    oa << data;
}
```

So that was

- change to `ptime`
- include the serialization header for `posix_time`.

The program prints:

```
22 serialization::archive 10 0 0 0  0  0 0 0 0 15 not-a-date-time
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71d32a5aa2bb52e8)**

Comment: wat if.. want the curreant system date and time..using same posix_time

Comment: @user3382670 [SO] is a perfect place for questions. There are many more people who can help and your question may help others, if it is any good. I'm not interested in removing all benefits from the process, and neither should you be :)

Comment: @user3382670 What about [searching for `[c++] ptime`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=ptime%20%5bc%2b%2b%5d)? High voted answers often help. It's not like you're the first person in the history of SO to want to use Boost Datetime to get the current date and time :0

Comment: ok.. 1 more doubt..wat if.. i want the current system date and time..using same posix_time in same above struct ??

Comment: @user3382670 That's not a doubt. That's laziness. Just give it some work first. Come back if you're stuck with a question that has _no answer_ on SO.

Comment: @user3382670: Not "doubts". **Questions**.